# Usage of "discriminating in"

Tags: prepositions

Sentence that needs correction:

> "Many believe that goats are not very discriminating ***in***  nourishment, but although they may eat many types of plants, they do not actually eat tin cans."

What's wrong with in?

How should the sentence be corrected?

Comment: What reasoning leads you to believe that *in* is incorrect?

Comment: I won't say its wrong, but it would be more natural to use **regarding their** or **in their** in place of *in*. Maybe its because a pronoun is needed for *nourishment*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several meanings of the word in, one of which is concerning or regarding.  So there is nothing wrong with "in". However, the phrase "in regard to their" will give a clear expression.